# A free boundary problem by finite difference method

Tags: elliptic-pde, differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I wanna discretize the following free boundary problem

Find $u$ and $\Omega$ such  that $\Delta u=1-\delta_0$ in $\Omega$ with the conditions $u=|\nabla u|=0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

I apply finite difference method and  I need to put some initial value on  stencil points around the origin and rotate. Could you help me how can I find  reasonable  initial values?

Comment: Is this in the plane?  Also, this looks like it would have a radially symmetric analytical solution.  why do you need a finite difference method for it.

Comment: Yes, it is in the plane. By potential theory techniques we can prove that $\Omega$ is a ball and then the symmetric analytical solution is determined but $\Omega$ is unknown in advanced. We are looking for a numerical solution of the multiphase version of the problem which has no analytical solution. 